# Getting node version via batch script

Tags: node.js, batch-file, cmd, scripting

I am learning both nodeJS and batch scripting and I would like to get the node version using a batch script.

Current code is this:

```
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`node --version`) DO (
SET NODE_VER=%%F
)
ECHO %NODE_VER%
pause
```

But I do not understand why this doesn't work.  It just freezes after calling command `node --version`.  I also tried calling `node -v` but same behavior. This exact command works when replacing `node --version` with `python --version`.  Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cmd` commands will always first read the local directory for a matching command, then it will go to the environment `%path%` to search for the command. In this instance, `Node` exists inside of the `%path%` variable, but you also have a `node.???` file in the local directory and will therefore be used. Therefore the following measures are important:

Never name batch files the same as executables. i.e use `my_node_script.cmd`
Always try and use the full executable name inside of the batch file `node.exe --version` and if possible rather use the full path to the executable, should you require a duplicate name such as `node` inside your working directory. Something like:

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" --version
```

or

```
"%ProgramFiles%\nodejs\node.exe" --version
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F %%F IN ('node.exe --version') DO ECHO %%F
PAUSE
GOTO :EOF
```